# Liquibase Export Data from Oracle Database - generateChangeLog

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to export data from an Oracle (ojdbc7) database using liquibase.

My property file has below options:

- driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
- url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
- username: user
- password: user
- outputChangeLogFile:src/main/resources/output.xml
- defaultSchemaName: USERS

In STS I used below command to generate the changelog
**liquibase:generateChangeLog -DdiffTypes="data"**

and through command prompt I used:
**mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -DdiffTypes="data"**

But nothing works, I got only crateTable commands not the insert queries.

Please guide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest try to export data via CLI liquibase version. Download it [here](http://www.liquibase.org/download/index.html), unpack, put ojdbc7.jar into liquibase folder:

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
      --classpath=\path\to\classes:ojdbc7.jar \
      --changeLogFile=db.changelog.xml \
      --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" \
      --username=user \
      --password=user \
      --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog
```

If everything will work fine we can move to the next step - try to migrate data via maven.

Comment: Thanks @Vladislav, it worked. Please guide how we can do this via maven.

Comment: Is it possible to export subset of data?

Comment: @ChandreshMishra I don't know any appropriate ways to do this, only by editing source file

Answer (score 12):

`mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.diffTypes=data`

should work